# How to import a OVA file to proxmox

Tags: proxmox

I'm having some trouble trying to import an ova image to my proxmox server. 
I followed the steps of extracting the ova file and then converted the vmdk file to a qcow2 file with :

```
qemu-img convert -f vmdk RADIUSdesk-2016-4-0-disk1.vmdk  -O qcow2 qcowdisk.qcow2
```

but according to many pages now I have to copy that file to the VM directory e.g.:

```
mv qcowdisk.qcow2 /var/lib/vz/images/115/vm-115-disk-1.qcow2
```

the problem is that even though I created the VM 115 the directory "115" doesn't exist, so I'm suspecting that this is a way to do it with probably the version 4 of proxmox but not 5, which is the one I have. Could anyone please help me what do I have to do in the last step?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Proxmox includes qm importdisk as command.

Extract your ova:

```
tar -xvf *.ova
```

Create a new VM without harddisks.

Import Your harddisks like this: (targetvmid is the vmnumber)

```
qm importdisk targetvmid disk001.vmdk local -format qcow2
```

Comment: I found that after I completed the import, I had to ADD the disk.  Using the web gui, under the Hardware tab, it will say the disk is "unused".  Click on the the unused disk, then click "Edit", then click the "Add" button.

You might have to enable the drive and change the boot order in the Options tab.  Simply click on Options, then "Boot Order" and "Edit".  Check the box next to the hard drives you just added and drag them up or down into the order needed for a successful boot.